# How to set the sa_mask in sigset_t?

Tags: c

gcc (GCC) 4.6.0
    c89

I have a signal handler declared like this:

```
   /* Setup signal handler */
    struct sigaction new_action;
    new_action.sa_handler = g_signal_handler;
    new_action.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to setup signal handlers.");
        return -1;
    }
```

When I was running my code through valgrind i.e. `valgrind --leak-check=full` it picked up the following error:

```
==5206== Syscall param rt_sigaction(act->sa_mask) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==5206==    at 0x347A435455: __libc_sigaction (in /lib64/libc-2.14.so)
```

So aftering looking at the man pages I decided to set like this, just to test with:

new_action.sa_mask = SA_NODEFER;

However, that just give me the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__sigset_t’ from type ‘int’
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* Signals blocked during the execution of the handler. */
sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&new_action.sa_mask, SIGINT);
```

> The `sa_mask` field allows us to specify a set of signals that aren’t
>   permitted to interrupt execution of this handler. In addition, the
>   signal that caused the handler to be invoked is automatically added
>   to the process signal mask.

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I went with the empty set. Worked fine and this time valgrind didn't complain.